# Creating table of images and only one col having one picture to span all rows

Tags: tables, graphics, formatting, multirow

I am just adding lots of images into latex and although I know how to apply images to a table, this one is slightly tricker.

I have two columns. The first needs a single image which spans all rows, and the second needs three separate images. I realise I need to use multirow and do, but it seems not to be working

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ c c }
\multirow{3}{\includegraphics[scale = 0.5]{images/woman-with-black-hat-1909- schiele.jpg}} &  \includegraphics[scale = 5]{images/sal10_24Sal.jpg} \\
 & \includegraphics[scale = 5]{images/sal50_24Sal.jpg} \\
& \includegraphics[scale = 5]{images/sal100_24Sal.jpg}\\ 
\end{tabular}
\caption{unused for the mo}
\label{fig:vincent}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing I had to change in your code was

```
\multirow{3}{*}{\includegraphics....}
```

which, from [the documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/multirow/multirow.pdf), is *to indicate that the text argument’s natural width is to be used.* You could also specify a width manually if that's your preference- see Section 2 of the documentation for more details and options.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cc}
  \multirow{3}{*}{\includegraphics[scale = 0.5]{images/woman-with-black-hat-1909- schiele.jpg}} &  \includegraphics[scale = 5]{images/sal10_24Sal.jpg} \\
                                                                                           & \includegraphics[scale = 5]{images/sal50_24Sal.jpg} \\
                                                                                           & \includegraphics[scale = 5]{images/sal100_24Sal.jpg}\\ 
\end{tabular}
\caption{unused for the mo}
\label{fig:vincent}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```